# How can i write this rm -rf /path/to/directory/* using execv()?

Tags: linux, unix

This will delete the entire directory

[image: This will delete the entire directory]

`rm -rf /path/to/directory/*` removes everything in a directory but I don't know how to write this command using `execv()`.

Comment: [do not post text in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). And why don't just use [`unlink`/`unlinkat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html)?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new on stackoverflow. I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: don't forget about security when implementing such thing; I would definitely try to provide / as arg on your server for this command :)

Comment: have you tried to read this? https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv

Comment: Yes, I have read this.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc i need to use [execv]. It is an exercise that i need to do for school.

Comment: To remove everything within a directory requires you to use opendir/readdir/closedir to find every file. If your directory has subdirectories, you'll need to recursively delete the contents of that directory (but make sure to ignore `.` and `..`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good luck,

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
 {

    char *params[4]  = {"/bin/rm", "-rf", argv[1]};

    int res = execv( "/bin/rm" , params);    

    return 0;
 }
```